# Synchronize the animation timing with data (ThreeJS)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, time, three.js

I have a data, Time in milliseconds and position(x,y,z) of object to be at that time.

```
msec    |poz_x  |poz_y  |poz_z
------------------------------
0       |318    |24     |3
25      |318    |24     |3
49      |318    |23     |3
70      |318    |22     |2
91      |318    |22     |2
113     |318    |21     |1
136     |318    |21     |1
e.t.c
```

The problem is that the time difference between actual and next data vary (coming from sensor). 
I'm looking for a way  to do the animation in real time.
If in my data I have 60 second of information, it need to animate in browser during 60 second.
I have read that `requestAnimationFrame( animate );` will repeat the function 60 time per second, but if my scene is heavy I imagine the frame rate will go down. In any case this can't solve my problem.

I'm looking for a robust solution that doesn't depend on the current framerate of the browser.
Please help.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Can you please ask me what question you have after reading, so I can explane better. Sure it will help to understand my problem to others too.
it's my first attempt to ask a questionhere because I don't see other way to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve that, with and without libraries.
And you are right, it is not quite as simple as just counting the number of ticks of the animation-loop as there is no guarantee it happens every 1/60 second. But the animation-frame callback (`loop` in the code below) will get a timestamp passed as first parameter that can be used to calculate animation-progress.

So, in javascript, that could be something like this:

```
// these are your keyframes, in a format compatible with THREE.Vector3. 
// Please note that the time `t` is expected in milliseconds here.
// (must have properties named x, y and z - otherwise the copy below doesn't work)
const keyframes = [
  {t: 0, x: 318, y: 24, z: 3},
  {t: 25, x: 318, y: 24, z: 3},
  // ... and so on
];

// find a pair of keyframes [a, b] such that `a.t < t` and `b.t > t`. 
// In other words, find the previous and next keyframe given the 
// specific time `t`. If no previous or next keyframes is found, null 
// is returned instead.
function findNearestKeyframes(t) {
  let prevKeyframe = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < keyframes.length; i++) {
    if (keyframes[i].t > t) {
      return [prevKeyframe, keyframes[i]];
    }
    prevKeyframe = keyframes[i];
  }

  return [prevKeyframe, null];
}

const tmpV3 = new THREE.Vector3();

function loop(t) {
  const [prevKeyframe, nextKeyframe] = findNearestKeyframes(t);

  // (...not handling cases where there is no prev or next here)

  // compute the progress of time between the two keyframes 
  // (0 when t === prevKeyframe.t and 1 when t === nextKeyframe.t)
  let progress = (t - prevKeyframe.t) / (nextKeyframe.t - prevKeyframe.t);

  // copy position from previous keyframe, and interpolate towards the 
  // next keyframe linearly
  tmpV3.copy(nextKeyframe);
  someObject.position
    .copy(prevKeyframe)
    .lerp(tmpV3, progress);

  // (...render scene)

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

// start the animation-loop
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

**EDIT:** To address one question from the comments about optimizing the `findNearestKeyframes`-function:

Once you get to several thousands of keyframes it might make sense to optimize that a bit, yes. For something like a few hundred it wouldn't be worth the effort (i'd categorize that as premature optimization).

To optimize, you could create an index-table in order to skip over irrelevant sections of the array. For instance, you could store the index in the keyframes-array for the start of every 10 seconds or something like that, that way - when you're searching for keyframes around t = 12.328s, you could start at a higher index based on precomputed information. There are probably a lot of other algorithms and structures that you could use to speed it up.

Comment: Do you think it can perform better if instead of  doing forward loop in findNearestKeyframes(t) we try to some type of doble loop in UP and Down direction from actual point of time. I'm relativity new in browser rendering so I'm not very familiar with how it perform. I'll try some comparison if find time.

Comment: By the way. There are something strange in your code I assume getNearestKeyframes(t) <==> findNearestKeyframes(t)

Comment: thanks, I corrected the wrong function-name and updated the answer with a bit on optimizing